# Retrieving a Variable result from a function in Kotlin and okhttp

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I am new to Kotlin and Your help is highly appreciated. I am able to get the value of jsonStringArray variable within getVariable() function but I am not sure how to retrieve the value outside the function in kotlin.

```
//Need help on the below variable outside getVariable function 
val output=jsonStringArray.getVariable()???     
//Working Code
private fun getVariable() {
val itemDetailURL="https://www.google.com"
val client= OkHttpClient()
val request= Request.Builder().url(itemDetailURL).build()
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback
{
    override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
        val jsonStringArray=response?.body()?.string()
        println("JSON Output: $jsonStringArray")

    }
    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
    }
}
)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should start with reading some of the [documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html) and [tutorials](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher for your response. I tried but no luck yet.

Comment: Sorry, in this case it was not Kotlin-specific but related to an external library (OkHttp). Instead of `enqueue` you could use `execute()` which blocks until response is available. This shouldn't be called in the main (default) thread or the GUI will be unresponsive. Alternatively, whatever you want to do on response should happen in `onResponse` (or called from there). Third way would be a Kotlin coroutine which can be more complicated in the beginning but can make things easier in the end.

Comment: Still Stuck in the same piece of code. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You should be more precise. Why do my proposed approaches not work?

Comment: I have tried that option already but the app is crashing.         val response=client.newCall(request).execute()
        val output=response?.body()?.string()
        println("Testing JSON Output:$output")  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxx.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Right now I converted bytestream() to string and made it work but I dont have solution for the above problem.

Comment: You can run the network code in another thread but be aware that GUI calls must be done in main thread. Alternatively you can follow the second or maybe the third suggestion I made earlier. Android (like other graphic OS's) is event driven. You initiate something and react when an event (like completion or failure of operation) happens.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I totally agree with you. Let us wait for others in case if they have a better solution for this problem that will be useful for others too.